# Подгрузка контета при скролинге React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Получить данные в json, завожу их в state. Вывожу через .map все данные на страницу.
Как осуществить чтоб выводилось допустим 10 записей, а при скролинге подгружались еще 10 записей и т.д.?

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, разобрался сам

Comment: дак напишите в ответе как разобрались, многим будет полезно